docxjs 8.5.0 Mathsize
How can I make the font size of the formula itself in this code in the latest version of docx size 14, by default formulas are created in size 10. here is the code:
const paragraph33 = new Paragraph({
                    children: [
                        new Math({
                            children: [
                                new MathRun(`Std=${window.STD.Sj}+${vaValuesJ2[i]}×`),
                                new MathFraction({
                                    numerator: [new MathRun(`${optionT3_2}`)],
                                    denominator: [new MathRun("7.2")],

                                }),
                                new MathRun(`-${window.STD.L}-${window.STD.C}=${Number(window.jResult['J2'].std[`va${i + 1}`]).toFixed(2)}`),

                            ],
                        }),
                    ],
                });
                paragraphs.push(paragraph33);

I will be very grateful if you show me an example of part of my code that I provided)
I looked in the documentation - I didn’t find the answer, the developer was also silent - there was no answer, I decided to ask people, maybe someone had encountered this
